# Electricity and magnetism

Tags: electromagnetism

If Div B = 0, where B = magnetic field intensity, then B must be a Curl of a some vector function. What is that vector function?

Answer (score 3):

It is called the **electromagnetic vector potential**, $\mathbf{A} (\mathbf{r},t)$.
$$
\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r},t) = \boldsymbol\nabla \times \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r},t)
$$
where the operator, $\boldsymbol\nabla \times$, is the curl. The electric field has also a part derived from it, as follows:
$$
\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r},t) = -\boldsymbol\nabla \phi (\mathbf{r},t) - \frac{\partial \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r},t)}{\partial t}
$$
where $\phi (\mathbf{r},t)$ is the scalar potential.

These two definitions arise from the Maxwell equations, however, $\mathbf{A}$ and $\phi$ are not unique, they can always be shifted by a continuous function, $\chi(\mathbf{r},t)$, such that, transforming
$$
\mathbf{A} (\mathbf{r},t) \rightarrow \mathbf{A} (\mathbf{r},t) + \boldsymbol\nabla \chi(\mathbf{r},t) \\
\phi (\mathbf{r},t) \rightarrow \phi (\mathbf{r},t) - \frac{\partial \chi(\mathbf{r},t)}{\partial t}
$$
will also satisfy the Maxwell equations. This is called **gauge transformation**.

Comment: A note for MathJax : I like $\:\boldsymbol{\nabla}, \boldsymbol{\times}\:$ in place of $\:\nabla, \times\:$

Comment: My browser doesn't show the difference, is one of them bold or something?

Comment: Yes, both of them are bold : `\boldsymbol{\nabla}, \boldsymbol{\times}`. They make the expressions more elegant. But since your browser doesn't show the difference it doesn't matter.

Comment: I think you edit these two symbols and your equations are more elegant, in my opinion of course. I suggest also to number your equations with   `\tag{}` so the users in their comments to  refer to these numbers. I could do it for you once here to see how, but  I must have your permission.

Comment: In any case here is a link very useful for editing in MathJax : [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/13183#mjx-eqn-eq3).

Comment: I generally tag equations when I need to refer to them in the answer or the answer has too many (more than 5, to be precise) equations since humans, at one glance, can not count things more than 5. But thanks for sharing your taste :)

Comment: Okay Oktay, wellcome.